# How do I convert a numeric string to its corresponding Unicode character?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

Given a string such as `"2764"` how can i programatically convert it to "\u2764"? Is there a built in function that will let me convert a standard string to its unicode-escaped equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr

```
>>> chr( int('2764', 16) )
❤
```

First convert your string to the number that is intended.  Then convert it to the corresponding character.

Comment: Thanks, although I just wanted to add that my number was actually in hex, so it chr( int('2764', 16)) worked